# Can't set global state from reduxForm to local state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

In user settings, I use `checkbox` in Redux Form. It works well but the issue occurs when using with local state for updating text.

I'm trying to add styles to `<label />` not `. So I have to switch design with local state like this:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isSex: true
    };
  }

  onToggle = () => {
    const { isSex } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      isSex: !isSex
    });
  };

  renderCheckBox() {
    const { isSex } = this.state;
    if (isSex) {
      return (
        <div>
          <i class="fas fa-male"></i> male
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <i class="fas fa-female"></i> female
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="formItem">
          <p>Sex</p>
          <div className="checkToggle">
            <label
              className="btn"
              htmlFor="is_sex"
              onClick={() => this.onToggle()}
            >
              {this.renderCheckBox()}
            </label>
            <Field
              name="is_sex"
              id="is_sex"
              component="input"
              type="checkbox"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
   )
  }
```

But I can't set global state fetched with Redux to local state. I tried like below in `matStateToProps` but the error occurs.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = { fetchUser };

function mapStateToProps({ user }) {
  return {
    initialValues: {
       is_sex: user.is_sex
    }
    this.setState({ isSex: user.is_sex });
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(reduxForm({ form: "userForm", enableReinitialize: true })(Settings));
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to me is here:

```
function mapStateToProps({ user }) { // 1. <----issue 
  return {
    initialValues: {
       is_sex: user.is_sex
    }
    this.setState({ isSex: user.is_sex }); // 2. <----Big issue
  };
}
```

1. In this line you are destructuring user property from state.
2. Infact `"this"` won't be referring to component.

Other than this in your dispatcher:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = { fetchUser };
```

If this `fetchUser` is a method to update the state/store then you have to dispatch some action. like:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => { 
      return {
        fetchUser : ()=> dispatch(fetchAction()) 
      };
}
```